# TensorFlow not finding CUDA drivers in wsl2

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run TensorFlow on my machine, but I am encountering some issues with CUDA drivers. When I run my code, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2023-04-19 17:13:12.944168: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-04-19 17:13:13.056290: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-04-19 17:13:13.057124: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-19 17:13:14.369949: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
>>> tf.__version__
'2.12.0'
```

1. **CUDA version:**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Feb__7_19:32:13_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0
```

2. **Nvidia drivers for the GPU**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.46                 Driver Version: 531.61       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650         On | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8                4W /  N/A|      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        24      G   /Xwayland                                 N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. **echo $PATH**

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin
```

4. **echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

```
/usr/local/cuda/include:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I have installed TensorFlow, CUDA drivers and cuDNN, but TensorFlow seems to be unable to find cuda drivers. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That error message is very poorly worded. It comes about because Tensorflow can’t load the correct version of the CUDA runtime library it needs. It doesn’t have anything to do with the drivers. As far as I am aware, there is no current official Tensorflow release with support for CUDA 12.1

Comment: Hi @Helios, Could you please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) and verify if you have followed all the steps correctly to install TensorFlow with GPU support for WSL2 in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: @talonmies : you should make this comment an answer, because it was the solution for me

Comment: @bokan: it’s not a complete answer -  if you have your own complete solution please add it. I don’t use or know anything about Tensorflow, other than how to read its source code and installation instructions